# PHP form (sometimes) feeds blank entries into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried creating a basic registration form (I'm pretty new to PHP).
The form works sometimes, but most of the times it's just sending blank entries into the MySQL database. Below is the code:

I have the following form:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
        <h2 class="sub-heading-agileits">Participant 1</h2>
        <div class="main-flex-w3ls-sectns">
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text1">
                <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Full Name" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text1">
                <select class="form-control" name="year1">
                                    <option>Year</option>
                                    <option value="1st Year">1st Year</option>
                                    <option value="2nd Year">2nd Year</option>
                                    <option value="3rd Year">3rd Year</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-flex-w3ls-sectns">
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text2">
                <input type="text" name="phone1" placeholder="Phone Number" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text2">
                <input type="text" name="college1" placeholder="College" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text">
            <input type="email" name="email1" placeholder="Email" required="">
        </div>
        <h2 class="sub-heading-agileits">Participant 2</h2>
        <div class="main-flex-w3ls-sectns">
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text1">
                <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text1">
                <select class="form-control" name="year2">
                                    <option>Year</option>
                                    <option value="1st Year">1st Year</option>
                                    <option value="2nd Year">2nd Year</option>
                                    <option value="3rd Year">3rd Year</option>
                                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-flex-w3ls-sectns">
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text2">
                <input type="text" name="phone2" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text2">
                <input type="text" name="college2" placeholder="College">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-agileinfo-spc form-w3-agile-text">
            <input type="email" name="email2" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

I'm sorry for the long form code.

This is the PHP code to post the data to the database:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "fic";
$password = "fic201718";
$dbname = "fic201718";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];
$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
$college1 = $_POST['college1'];
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$year2 = $_POST['year2'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
$college2 = $_POST['college2'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO identitytheft (Participant1Name,Participant1Year,Participant1Phone,Participant1College,Participant1eMail,Participant2Name,Participant2Year,Participant2Phone,Participant2College,Participant2eMail) VALUES ('$name1','$year1','$phone1','$college1','$email1','$name2','$year2','$phone2','$college2','$email2')";
$conn->query($sql);
if (!empty($_POST['name1'])) {
    echo ("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Successfully Registered'); </script>");
}
```

However, the form sometimes inserts absolutely blank data into the database. It sometimes works though.

One thing that I have noticed is, I do not get blank rows if there are no special characters in the responses. My columns are set to utf8_unicode_ci (all of the columns). Could there be something wrong here?
Please help?

Comment: When blank data is inserted to the database, is it every value it blank or some of the values? A tip for you moving forward: your variable names should match the database column names. It helps to make sure everything is lined up.

Comment: Hey, every column is blank. It's not just a particular column. Nothing is fed into the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Form sends blank data to mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955976/php-form-sends-blank-data-to-mysql)

Comment: Hey, that's the only form connected to the only table in the database.

Comment: It's never a good idea to insert data into a database without first validating the data. In php, you should at least use `mysqli_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php. If you were validating your data before submitting, you would also be able to detect and catch empty forms.

Comment: Hey, form validation is being done using javascript. I'm pretty sure there are no blank forms being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If your POST variables aren't empty and the data you see is what you expect then it isn't your form and most like your query. Use var_dump to check your post variables after the form submission.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The first thing I will note is that you current approach is susceptible to SQL injection, so you'll want to clean up your code. Look up prepared statments http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

I'll clean up your current query, which should work for you. I obviously don't have your database setup, so I can test it. You don't have to format it like I did and I don't usually format it this way unless I'm debugging -- it helps align the column names with the values.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "fic";
$password = "fic201718";
$dbname = "fic201718";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];
$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
$college1 = $_POST['college1'];
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$year2 = $_POST['year2'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
$college2 = $_POST['college2'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO identitytheft (
    Participant1Name,
    Participant1Year,
    Participant1Phone,
    Participant1College,
    Participant1eMail,
    Participant2Name,
    Participant2Year,
    Participant2Phone,
    Participant2College,
    Participant2eMail)
    VALUES (
    '".$name1."',
    '".$year1."',
    '".$phone1."',
    '".$college1."',
    '".$email1."',
    '".$name2."',
    '".$year2."',
    '".$phone2."',
    '".$college2."',
    '".$email2."'
)";
$conn->query($sql);
if (!empty($_POST['name1'])) {
    echo ("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Successfully Registered'); </script>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, I've just started learning - I'll get to the part of protecting the data from SQL Injections pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will check the code and let you know if it solves the problem.

Also, formatting the code like yours is a better idea. I'll do it whenever I write any code in the future.

Comment: Hey, no luck

It still gives me some responses as totally blank.
One thing that I have noticed is, I do not get blank rows if there are no special characters in the responses. My columns are set to utf8_unicode_ci (all of the columns). Could there be something wrong here?

Comment: What is the datatype set to? varchar? int? -- more than likely it doesn't have anything to do with the collation

Comment: Data type is set to varchar(255) for all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($varname) && !empty($varname)){
  sql statements over here within php code
}
```

you can add this similar type of code,as it works only when the input fields are not empty and does not post non empty data into your database